# Replace all titles default tooltip with jQuery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I'm trying to replace default tooltip (title="***") for all elements from my app using a small jQuery script that allows me to define a custom tooltip.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" title="default tooltip" />
    <textarea type="text" title="default tooltip"></textarea>
    <select title="default tooltip"><option>select</option></select>
 </div>
```

.

```
$(function() {
$('input, textarea, select, p, label').tooltip({
hide: {
effect: "explode",
delay: 250
}
});
});
```

check fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tnEmZ/1/

Comment: You want to keep same tooltip message for all elemnets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $title = $("a,input,p,label,textarea[title]"); //get all elements with the title-Attribute

//loop through title-elements
$.each($title, function(index, value) {
    $(this).tooltip({
        show: {
             effect: "explode",
             delay: 250
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            delay: 250
       }
    });  
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pisi2012/JJxET/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KP7mT/)** will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Tooltip only Text
        $('.masterTooltip').hover(function(){
                // Hover over code
                var title = $(this).attr('title');
                $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
                $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
                .text(title)
                .appendTo('body')
                .fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
                // Hover out code
                $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
                $('.tooltip').remove();
        }).mousemove(function(e) {
                var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
                var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
                $('.tooltip')
                .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
        });
});
```

---

Another example **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6WDZm/)** with `jquery tooltip`.

Source: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip widget is not part of jQuery but of jQueryUI. Besides, it won't work on your jsfiddle as the tooltip widget came with jQueryUI 1.9.0, and your jsfiddle use jQueryUI 1.8.3. Refer [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) for more information.